# sed delete code block from file

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I want to remove the `server {...}` code block from the default nginx configuration server configuration file.

`sudo sed -i '/(\s*#?)server \s*{(?:[\s\S]+)\1}/ d' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

produces `sed: -e expression #1, char 33: Invalid back reference`

However using tools like [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) the match works just fine. Essentially what I need to do is match the code block based on matched indentation otherwise too much will be deleted.

---

You can test this yourself in Rubular using the default nginx config as a test string:

```
#user  nobody;
#Defines which Linux system user will own and run the Nginx server

worker_processes  1;
#Referes to single threaded process. Generally set to be equal to the number of CPUs or cores.

#error_log  logs/error.log; #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#Specifies the file where server logs. 

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
#nginx will write its master process ID(PID).

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # worker_processes and worker_connections allows you to calculate maxclients value: 
    # max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    # anything written in /opt/nginx/conf/mime.types is interpreted as if written inside the http { } block

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    # If serving locally stored static files, sendfile is essential to speed up the server,
    # But if using as reverse proxy one can deactivate it

    #tcp_nopush     on;
    # works opposite to tcp_nodelay. Instead of optimizing delays, it optimizes the amount of data sent at once.

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    # timeout during which a keep-alive client connection will stay open.

    #gzip  on;
    # tells the server to use on-the-fly gzip compression.

    server {
        # You would want to make a separate file with its own server block for each virtual domain
        # on your server and then include them.
        listen       80;
        #tells Nginx the hostname and the TCP port where it should listen for HTTP connections.
        # listen 80; is equivalent to listen *:80;

        server_name  localhost;
        # lets you doname-based virtual hosting

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #The location setting lets you configure how nginx responds to requests for resources within the server.
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` doesn't allow regex to span multiple lines, so you would need to use multiple commands to achieve what you want, e.g. something like:

```
'/(\s*#?)server\s*\{/,/\1\}/d'
```

But unfortunately sed doesn't allow back references from previous regexes, so the above doesn't work.

Comment: I dunno. I want to upvote this because it's a good point. I want to downvote it because it doesn't work. But you SAY it doesn't work, right in the answer. So conflicted!  :-)  (Oh, also, only certain variants of sed support shorthand like `\s`. If your answer only works with GNU sed, it's best to say so in the answer. Perhaps the OP is using OSX or *BSD!)

Comment: Sorry, but `sed` is not the right tool for this, and OP mentions sed in the title, so I decided to inform OP that it is not possible with sed

Comment: I've given up on sed and I'm trying to use perl now, but I have a new issue where it's replacing more than it should. `sudo perl -p0e 's/(\s*)#?server \s*{([?:\s\S]+)\1}//mg' /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here.

First, by default, sed uses BRE as its regular expression format. You either need to write your regexes in BRE, or you need to use an option for sed that tells it to interpret ERE. The option will depend on your platform, which you haven't shared as a tag, so read your man page for sed to see what to use.

Second, in order to process text over multiple lines, you need to have those multiple lines in your edit buffer. You do this by appending them to your hold buffer as you step through the file, then processing them all at once.  This is highly advanced sed usage, and more difficult than most people can deal with.  Even if we can put together something that works, it will read like line noise and be virtually unsupportable after-the-fact.

I'd suggest using awk instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# pay attention to are "start of server" line,
/^[[:space:]]*server {/ { n=1 }

# increment bracket counter within the server block,
n>0 && /^[[:space:]]*{/ { n++ }

# decrement the bracket counter within the server block,
n>0 && /^[[:space:]]*}/ { n-- }

# and if we're still within the block, skip to the next line.
n>0 { next }

# short-hand for "print the current line"
1
```

Note that the conditions contain `n>0` rather than just `n` because awk considers ***any non-zero value*** to evaluate to "true".

Note also that this will only work on files that contain a single squirly bracket per line.  I'm not sure whether nginx requires this, but if it permits closing a section within a section using `} }`, beware that the script above will not parse that correctly.

YMMV. Not tested on animals. May contain nuts.